# Memory leak in MjpegView

Tags: android, streaming, mjpeg

I am developing an android application that uses MjpegView(custom view for streaming video). When the user enter first time to application the streaming 
works great, but when the user starts to go to other screens and then return back to the streaming screen the application becomes slower than usual.

After reading few articles about memory leaks and find them threw eclipse, I tried to check my application and noticed each time when the user go to other screen (other than the streaming screen) the threads of the streaming still exists, is it normal?

```
    public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    public final static int     POSITION_UPPER_LEFT     = 9;
    public final static int     POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT    = 3;
    public final static int     POSITION_LOWER_LEFT     = 12;
    public final static int     POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT    = 6;

    public final static int     SIZE_STANDARD           = 1;
    public final static int     SIZE_BEST_FIT           = 4;
    public final static int     SIZE_FULLSCREEN         = 8;

    private MjpegViewThread     thread;
    private MjpegInputStream    mIn                     = null;
    private boolean             showFps                 = true;
    private volatile boolean    mRun                    = false;    //volatile for fixing JIT unchanied all for thread => accures when opening and then closing drawer
    private boolean             surfaceDone             = false;
    private Paint               overlayPaint;
    private int                 overlayTextColor;
    private int                 overlayBackgroundColor;
    private int                 ovlPos;
    private int                 dispWidth;
    private int                 dispHeight;
    private int                 displayMode;
    private boolean             resume                  = false;

    private Context             context;
    private int                 streamWidth;
    private int                 streamHeight;

    public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread
    {
        private SurfaceHolder   mSurfaceHolder;
        private int             frameCounter    = 0;
        private long            start;
        private Bitmap          ovl;

        public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context)
        {
            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        }

        private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh)
        {
            int tempx;
            int tempy;
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD)
            {
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT)
            {
                float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
                bmw = dispWidth;
                bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
                if (bmh > dispHeight)
                {
                    bmh = dispHeight;
                    bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
                }
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN) return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
            return null;
        }

        public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height)
        {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
            {
                dispWidth = width;
                dispHeight = height;
            }
        }

        private Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text)
        {
            Rect b = new Rect();
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
            int bwidth = b.width() + 2;
            int bheight = b.height() + 2;
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
            p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
            c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
            p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
            c.drawText(text, -b.left + 1, (bheight / 2) - ((p.ascent() + p.descent()) / 2) + 1, p);
            return bm;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
            int width;
            int height;
            Rect destRect;
            Canvas c = null;
            Paint p = new Paint();
            String fps = "";
            try
            {
                if (mIn != null && mRun)
                {
                    //clear the buffer when the user in other place except measurement screen
                    int availableBytes = mIn.available();
                    mIn.skipBytes(availableBytes);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (mRun)
            {
                if (surfaceDone)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (mIn != null && c != null)
                                {
                                    Bitmap bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                                    destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());

                                    if (streamHeight == -1 && streamWidth == -1)
                                    {
                                        streamWidth = bm.getWidth();
                                        streamHeight = bm.getHeight();
                                    }
                                    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                    c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                                    if (showFps)
                                    {
                                        p.setXfermode(mode);
                                        if (ovl != null)
                                        {
                                            height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom - ovl.getHeight();
                                            width = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right - ovl.getWidth();
                                            c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                        }
                                        p.setXfermode(null);
                                        frameCounter++;
                                        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000)
                                        {
                                            fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter) + "fps";
                                            frameCounter = 0;
                                            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                            ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                            }
                            catch (IllegalArgumentException e1)
                            {
                                Log.d("anton", "IllegalArgumentException");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getStreamWidth()
    {
        return streamWidth;
    }

    public int getStreamHeight()
    {
        return streamHeight;
    }

    private void init(Context context)
    {

        this.context = context;
        streamHeight = -1;
        streamWidth = -1;
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
        setFocusable(true);
        if (!resume)
        {
            resume = true;
            overlayPaint = new Paint();
            overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
            overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
            overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
            ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
            displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
            dispWidth = getWidth();
            dispHeight = getHeight();
            Log.i("AppLog", "init");
        }
    }

    public void startPlayback()
    {
        if (mIn != null)
        {
            mRun = true;
            if (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED)
            {
                thread.start();
            }
            else
            {
                resumePlayback();
            }
        }
    }

    public MjpegInputStream getStream()
    {
        return mIn;
    }

    public boolean isStreamingRunning()
    {
        return mRun;
    }

    public void resumePlayback()
    {
        mRun = true;
        init(context);
        Log.i("AppLog", "resume");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stopPlayback()
    {
        streamHeight = -1;
        streamWidth = -1;
        mRun = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            try
            {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h)
    {
        thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h);
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        surfaceDone = false;
        stopPlayback();
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        surfaceDone = true;
    }

    public void showFps(boolean b)
    {
        showFps = b;
    }

    public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source)
    {
        mIn = source;
        startPlayback();
    }

    //for swapping streams small/big mjpeg surfaces
    public void setStreamSource(MjpegInputStream source)
    {
        mIn = source;
    }

    public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p)
    {
        overlayPaint = p;
    }

    public void setOverlayTextColor(int c)
    {
        overlayTextColor = c;
    }

    public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c)
    {
        overlayBackgroundColor = c;
    }

    public void setOverlayPosition(int p)
    {
        ovlPos = p;
    }

    public void setDisplayMode(int s)
    {
        displayMode = s;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.performClick();
    }

}
```

[image: eclipse HPROF profiling screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember to `stopPlayback()` and `freeCameraMemory()` in the `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods of your activity/fragment